# Unknown group [somenamehere] in stateoverride

Tags: command-line, permissions, dpkg, sudo

I'm not the most knowledgeable Ubuntu user, so I may be a bit slow to understand a few solutions, and this morning I have run into quite a few problems.

First, my user was suddenly not sudo anymore (and it is the only user on my PC) so I went to the recovery mode, opened the root terminal and tried to add my user to the sudo group. To my surprise, the prompt said there wasn't one. I did some googling and found out that I should just create one and add myself to it and that is what I did.

After that, I rebooted, logged in and tried installing Spotify as I initially wanted, got past the password prompt and started downloading it but it gave me an error saying:

```
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 unknown group 'lp' in statoverride file
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Back to Google I went and saw a few answers saying that I should just remove a group from statoverride with this command:

```
sudo sed -i '/lp/d' /var/lib/dpkg/statoverride
```

I did that, tried installing Spotify again and the error came back but the group name had changed, it was *crontab* now. I ran the above command but with the crontab, and now it is giving me the same error but with *mlocate*.

I'd really appreciate if someone could shed some light on this problem for me, is there any solution for it?

Comment: It looks like you destroyed/overwrote your `/etc/group` file - that's why no groups at all are to be found. To confirm my suspicion please [edit] your question with the results of `ls -l /etc/group` and `wc /etc/group`.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following command in terminal:

```
groupadd lp
```